# Missing some spoon steps (plugins) at runtime (KarafLifecycleListener Error)

Tags: osgi, pentaho, kettle, osgi-bundle, karaf

I am using open-source Pentaho distribution from github.com (version 6.1-SNAPSHOT).

In Spoon there are some step missing (e.g. There is no Mongodb input/output step listed) and I cant add dataservice to step (There are no errors, this option just isn't on the list).

I have reinstalled everything (removed .kettle and .pentaho directories as well as whole source and distribution) but it didn't help.

This is what I get at spoon startup:

> 16:05:50,304 INFO  [KarafInstance]
>
> ---
>
> *** Karaf Instance Number: 1 at ~/pentaho-kettle/d** 
>      **ist/./system/karaf//data1**                                             
>    **Karaf Port:8801**                                                         
>    **OSGI Service Port:9050                                                  ***
>
> ---
>
> Dec 23, 2015 4:05:51 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback
>   lockAquired
>
> INFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
>
> 2015/12/23 16:05:53 - cfgbuilder - Warning: The configuration
>   parameter [org] is not supported by the default configuration builder
>   for scheme: sftp
>
> Dec 23, 2015 4:05:58 PM
>   org.pentaho.caching.impl.PentahoCacheManagerFactory$RegistrationHandler$1
>   onSuccess INFO: New Caching Service registered
>
> 16:06:04,009 ERROR [KarafLifecycleListener] The Kettle Karaf Lifycycle
>   Listener failed to execute properly. Releasing lifecycle hold, but
>   some services may be unavailable.

I suspect that

> ERROR [KarafLifecycleListener] The Kettle Karaf Lifycycle Listener
>   failed to execute properly. Releasing lifecycle hold, but some
>   services may be unavailable.

has something to do with it as missing plugins reside somewhere under karaf/ directory.

It was working just fine week ago.
I am using Ubuntu 15.04.

I will be grateful for any hints.

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using a non stable release. this is the place where you can download the latest stable release http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with jipipayo, For Pentaho CE version, download it from http://community.pentaho.com/ official instead of github. It is highly possible that the codes in github might be in unstable condition.

Also in case you have a missing plugin, try using the [Pentaho Marketplace](http://community.pentaho.com/marketplace/plugins/) and download the required plugins.

Hope this helps :)